# fotorama wordpress plugin one page vertical link

Tags: fotorama

I installed fotorama plug in wordpress here :
http://62.210.136.123/wordpress/
I would like to add an vertical sign to the gallery so as to make a link to the bottom part of the page exactly like this
http://www.amillarah.com/

I saw the source code below

```
<span class="control  control--down  js-jumpto-main"></span>
```

but i don't know how to implement control--down on the plugin wordpress

Please help me

Many thanks

Rodolphe CATTA